# Kafka producer timeout on Ubuntu over VPN

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, vpn

I recently switched from a Windows laptop to an Ubuntu laptop for work related developement.

We have a kafka server - lets call it `my-kafka-server` - and I have not had any issues consuming and producing messages from my Windows laptop, be it on site or over VPN.

On my Ubuntu laptop however I connect to a different VPN server, and I have had to ask for port openings related to this VPN server for many of the hosts and ports I depend upon. The kafka broker was no exception. It is a single node cluster (yes I know) - and I have requested opening of 2181 (zookeper) as well as 9092, 9093 and 9094 for the kafka nodes.

I am now able to consume message, but I am still consistently unable to produce messages. All my efforts end similar to this:

```
m66523@m66523-ThinkPad-X280:~/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin$ echo "Hello, World" | ./kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server my-kafka-server:9092 --topic alive-test
[2022-02-03 12:33:39,598] ERROR Error when sending message to topic alive-test with key: null, value: 12 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for alive-test-0:120001 ms has passed since batch creation
```

Does anyone hoave an idea - what am I missing?

Comment: Please add your kafka consumer and producer configurations. seems to be properties issue.

Comment: @Umeshwaran I have no consumer- and produce configurations except from what appears on the command line.

Comment: This works: `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server my-kafka-server:9092 --topic some-topic` - but this does not not `echo "Hello, World" | ./kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server my-kafka-server:9092 --topic some-topic`

Comment: Also it usually works from a springboot application - on my windows laptop - but not on my Ubuntu laptop. I expect that this is not really a question of Windows or Ubuntu though.

Comment: If you search for `has passed since batch creation` you'll find all the information you need. You need to make the producer flush itself. I don't think piping data into it will cause that to happen

Comment: @OneCricketeer I just tried the exact same command from another linux server and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I should mention that I only use the kafka command line scripts here because it illustrates the problem. But in fact I first encountered the problem with a springboot application. This application is running with the exact same configuration properties regardless which laptop I am running it from. The application is able to consume but not produce on my ubuntu laptop. Everywhere else it works as intended.

Comment: My point is that the networking setup isn't the only problem. There is a message that is not being flushed by the producer within the default `120000 ms`, and that is why the log happens. Did the port get opened for **all** the brokers in the cluster? What happens if you give multiple brokers in your command? Can you `nc -vz kafka-server 9092` and get a successful connection for them all?

Comment: You are right - 9093 and 9094 are not open yet it seems. I will wait for them to be opened and then give an update:)

Answer (score 0):

Opening the ports 9093 and 9094 solved the issue :-)